# ASP.NET MVC Task.Run running status

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task

I want to run a task like below :

```
Task.Run(() => GetWeatherAsync());
```

And this task only sleeps for 20 seconds :

```
public async void GetWeatherAsync()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
}
```

I want to prevent new user to enter to this scope (Method) until the previous Process is running .

What happens if the current user is waiting in `GetWeatherAsync` and new user enter .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Task.Run` doesn't make your method async. Just use the `GetWeatherAsync` method without another overhead (because it's already async) and ASP.NET runs each request in a new thread. You don't need another thread here.
You should not use `async void`.
You should not use `Thread.Sleep` in async methods. It's `Task.Delay` here.
You can use locking here to achieve your goal:

```
// only 1 thread can be granted access at a time
static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

public async Task GetWeatherAsync()
{
   // If no-one has been granted access to the Semaphore, code execution will proceed, 
   // otherwise this thread waits here until the semaphore is released 
   await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(); 
   try
   {
       await Task.Delay(20000); // Your code here
   }
   finally
   {
      semaphoreSlim.Release();
   }
}
```

P.S.
You need to start reading [this Persian course about C# 5, Async](http://www.dotnettips.info/courses/details/14).

Comment: Thanks dear Vahid,
But I could not call async method from the action method

Comment: I want call GetWeatherAsync() inside action method without awaiting it causes.

Comment: So it's better to call it from a background task: http://www.dotnettips.info/post/1736